'object too deep for desired array' when using curve_fit deal with 2-dimensional function
So I am trying to fit a 2-dimensional function with polynomials.
I have some data and I have written a function to test it.
But something unexpected happens like:
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
Then I go to the net but found nothing like my situation. I have no idea how to flatten my data.What should I  do to fix this problem?
Code

def poly(order, cov, x):

    z = 0

    for r in range(order + 1):

        for k in range(order + 1):

           z += cov[r * order + k] * x[0] ** r * x[1] ** k

    return z

    

def polynomial_func(x , *cov):

    order = int(np.sqrt(len(cov))) - 1 

    return poly(order, cov, x)



k = int(input('Please type the order:')) 

U = sorted(list(u))

V = sorted(list(v))[300:501]

U = U*201

V0 = []

for item in V:

    V0 = V0 + [item]*151

V = V0

arr_x = np.array(U[::3])

arr_y = np.array(V[::3])

arr_z = g(arr_x,arr_y)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(polynomial_func, (arr_x,arr_y), arr_z , p0=[0.0] * (k+1)**2)

print(np.round(popt, 2))

Where u and v are some random x y and g is the fuction generated by interpolation)
I have gone through the Web.
This problem seems commonly due to 2-D array, but I have no idea how to deal with them.
Is this happens because of arr_z?


The arrays x, y, z should have one dimension.
The curve_fit() requires a single dimension array.
You can use flatten():

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def g(x, y):
    return x + y


def poly(order, cov, x):
    z = 0
    for r in range(order + 1):
        for k in range(order + 1):
            z += cov[r * (order + 1) + k] * x[0] ** r * x[1] ** k
    return z


def polynomial_func(xy, *cov):
    order = int(np.sqrt(len(cov))) - 1
    x, y = xy[0], xy[1]
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        z[i] = poly(order, cov, (x[i], y[i]))
    return z


np.random.seed(1)

u, v = np.random.rand(1000), np.random.rand(1000)
k = 2

U, V = sorted(list(u)), sorted(list(v))[300:501]

min_len = min(len(U), len(V))
U, V = U[:min_len], V[:min_len]
U = U * (201 // min_len)

V0 = []

for item in V:
    V0 += [item] * 151

V = V0


min_len = min(len(U), len(V))
U, V = U[:min_len], V[:min_len]

arr_x, arr_y = np.array(U[::3]), np.array(V[::3])

min_len = min(len(arr_x), len(arr_y))
arr_x, arr_y = arr_x[:min_len], arr_y[:min_len]
arr_z = g(arr_x, arr_y)

arr_x, arr_y, arr_z = arr_x.flatten(), arr_y.flatten(), arr_z.flatten()

xy = np.vstack((arr_x, arr_y))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(polynomial_func, xy, arr_z, p0=[0.0] * (k + 1) ** 2)

print(np.round(popt, 2))


Prints

[ 0.24 -0.57  2.52  0.97  0.18 -0.29 -0.01  0.08 -0.13]

